# How do I turn off the LEDs on the YWRobot ICE Box - RPI Fan V1?

Tags: led

I'm using the YWRobot ICE Box - RPI Fan V1 on my RPi stack.  The Blue LEDs are annoying, does anyone know how to turn them off?  Permanently?

Thanks.

Comment: Put some tape over them.  I can't see any PI relevance.

Comment: nail polish is neater than tape

Comment: Tape has the advantage of being slightly easier to remove.

Comment: And tape doesn't stink of solution chemicals. Otherwise, de-solder the LEDs

Comment: Thanks all.  I'll go with de-soldering them.